# Problem with margin when using ID/CLASS defining LI in CSS

Tags: css

I am having problems using CSS and margins. I have a list that the li has a margin-bottom: 10px; but i want to deactivate this margin inside the list because I've a sub-list. It's a litle hard to explain, because English is not my main language, but you can check the [example of what happens](http://jsfiddle.net/ueyd5/1/).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. Why not add the margin-bottom to the ul if you don't want any margin in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a specificity problem. Your 'general' (`#content-sidebar li`) style is more specific than your specific styles.

Here are a few articles going into more detail about CSS specificity

http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Anyhoo, is this the effect you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/ueyd5/10/

```
#content-sidebar li {margin-bottom:10px;}
#content-sidebar .content-sidebar-box {background:blue}
#content-sidebar .content-sidebar-submenu {background:red;}
#content-sidebar  .content-sidebar-submenu li {margin-bottom: 0;}
```

Comment: @thirtydot ah yes. was looking for some references to add. Updated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

@jquinn; just write this

`#content-sidebar .content-sidebar-submenu li {margin-bottom: 0;}`

in you css.
the reason why this happening because `#content-sidebar li` is more specific or more powerfull then your `.content-sidebar-submenu li`

http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/ueyd5/3/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want correctly, then [here's your answer](http://jsfiddle.net/ueyd5/9/). Your `margin:0` wasn't overriding, because IDs always have priority over just classes. Add the ID in to the second call and you're golden.

On a side note, you don't need to wrap the sublists in a `<div>`. My fiddle, above also shows this.